# Inverse of $2 \times 2$ block matrices

Tags: matrices, inverse, block-matrices

Let matrices $A, B, C, D$ be invertible. How can I find the inverse of the following block matrix?

$$\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As $D$ is invertible, the block matrix is invertible if and only if the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $D$ --- i.e. the matrix $S=A-BD^{-1}C$ --- is invertible. In that case, you can see Wikipedia for the block matrix inversion formula.

Answer (score 11):

It is not necessarily invertible at all -- certainly not if, for example, $A=B$ and $C=D$.

Conversely, the block matrix can be invertible even if neither of the blocks are. In cases such as
$$ \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\ \hline 0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{array}\right] \quad\text{or}\quad
\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}1&0&0&1\\0&2&1&0\\ \hline 0&2&2&0\\2&0&0&1\end{array}\right]
$$
you can even have $AD-BC=0$, so attempting to extend determinant-based methods to block matrices seems to be doomed to failure.

Comment: Also, determinant-based methiods, such as the adjugate matrix, are in many cases based on the fact that the elements in the matrix commutes. For instance, taking the OP's matrix and multiplying it with its block-adjoint (from the right) will give
$$
\begin{bmatrix}AD-BC&BA-AB\\CD-DC&DA-CB\end{bmatrix}
$$where the diagonal entries are not necessarily equal, and the off-diagonal entries are not necessarily zero.